# Set SPN same as UPN with Centrify on Linux

Tags: linux, kerberos, spn, upn, centrify

Hi I'm configuring Kerberos with Centrify on a linux environment. I'm much more familiar with Windows.

I know with MIT Kerberos in Linux, I can create a new account using the SPN as UPN. Is this the same processes when using Centrify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centrify leverages Active Directory (Microsoft Kerberos) and once you succesfully join a Linux system to AD via Centrify, the Kerberos settings get automatically populated.

You don't have to worry about /etc/krb5.conf or keytab files.  These are maintained for you also when you Add/Remove domains (realms) or domain controllers (KDCs).

As far as creating accounts, is there something specific that you want the account for?  Accounts are typically created in Active Directory.  Users have UPNs;  SPNs apply to services running typically on systems.

If what you want to do is to use a keytab, you can use the adkeytab command.

You can also use the Centrify Community as well.